# Azure data factory capturing start time and end time and calculate time difference for each activity in the pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I have a Azure Data Factory pipeline already set up with a few databricks notebook activities. How can I capture the start time and end time for EACH notebook activity and display the start time,end time and time difference in my customized email configuration in logic apps?

Comment: if you have logs enable on data factory you could query log analytics to get these information i imagine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-metrics-alerts

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as shown in below screenshot.

I have used `@string(utcnow())` expression for `StartTime` and `EndTime` Set variable activities.

[image]

To sent these time_difference over mail you can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email)

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/662759/capture-and-log-start-and-end-timestamp-of-adf-pip.html